# Stripboard/veroboard/matrix board design software

Tags: design, stripboard, stripboard

I'm prototyping a simple layout for a small project on matrix board, but figured there must be a better way than drawing it all out on paper. Are there any aimed at matrix board?

I've found the following software for stripboard, but nothing explicitly for matrix board:

- [DIY Layout Creator](http://diy-fever.com/software/)
- [Stripboard Designer](http://3dreplicators.com/New%20Front%20Page/Documentation/Tools/Stripboard%20designer.htm)
- Stripboard Magic (seems to be abandonware, but there's page about it [here](http://www.marlwifi.org.nz/other/stripboard-magic/))
- [VeeCAD](http://veecad.com/) Stripboard Editor Limited free version, designed to integrate well with [TinyCAD](http://tinycad.sourceforge.net/)
- [VeroDes](http://www.heyrick.co.uk/software/verodes/)

Any more I've missed? Any recommendations?

Comment: I don't have the reputation to answer the question but VeroRoute might also be of interest: https://sourceforge.net/projects/veroroute/

Answer (score 24):

[Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/) looks like the ideal tool for this:

- Free (GPL license)
- Multi platform (Linux, Mac OS, Windows)
- Integrates a large library of components

The stripboard can be resized, you can chose the strips to be vertical or horizontal. You can also cut the contacts with your mouse like you would do in real life.

Example circuit:
[image: Fritzing simple stripboard Arduino circuit]

Edit 30/10/2018:
Make sure you add a `Stripboard` and not a `Perfboard`, the `Stripboard` is the one circled by the dark red square on the following screenshot: (third item on the first row)

[image: Add Stripboard image]

Comment: This is absolutely the best!!!

Comment: Victor, how did you get that copper PCB board to show on your fritzing tool?  Mine is just a gray background with no holes.

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit I have tested again with Fritzing 0.9.3b on Kubuntu 18.04. Make sure you add a `Stripboard` and not a `Perfboard` (they are right next to each other, the `Stripboard` is the one on the right).

Comment: Fritzing is a nice software, but useless for perfboards. It does not even let you flip the board over to plan out the routes, which is kind of THE feature you need to perfboards...

Comment: How do I show the perfboard so that I can see where under the Arduino the strips are drilled?

Comment: How do I find components that are designed from top view? E.g. your voltage regulator takes too much space. It wastes 7*3 holes.

Comment: Apparently Fritzing is no longer free.  They want about 10 bucks to download it.  While that's not very much money, I'd like to see if it meets my needs before I needlessly  spend anything on it.  I'd gladly pay the $10 if it does.

Answer (score 8):

As Leon suggested I would use PCB design program.

I have done this in two ways.

1. Create a land pattern that is a strip of holes or a matrix of holes 
   (no silkscreen). Place a couple of these patterns down and you have a 
   large grid.
2. Sometimes I just use vias to create a matrix.

I made two footprints for vector pins. One for the Vector T42-1 micro clips
another for the K24A gold pins. I place these pins on the 100mil x 100mil
grid. I use the copper routes on different PCB layers (with different colors)
to represent wires.

The nice thing about the PCB program is you can check connectivity against your schematic.
You won't have that benefit in a drawing program.

Answer (score 7):

Soft Circuit Editor by Atarado [here](https://www.atarado.com/electronics-circuit-software-download-page.html).

- Free (as in zero purchase price)
- Windows and Linux
- Two-windows - schematic and layout.
- Supports normal stripboard
- Supports Atarado's proprietary stripboard layouts.
- Very limited component library?

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: While I agree that link-only answers have their weaknesses, one cannot attach executables to SE answers (nor would it be legal to, in some cases).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The idea clearly is not to post an executable, but to post at least sufficient information about why the given link is relevant, what value the recommended product brings in the context of the question, and also sufficient information to find the product in the future, as and when the specific link dies of link rot. This isn't new, it has been the norm on this site for as long as I have been here.

Comment: I edited the Answer to include some details of the product. I downloaded SCE to make a screenshot (to avoid stepping on copyright toes) and found there's no user documentation and I can't work out how to delete, move or rotate components.

Comment: Doubleclick on component rotate it clocwise, shift+2click ccw; that's for schematic, and for layouts non-stretching components. Stretching components in layout, click on pin and drag...There is lot of hidden features with ctrl+alt+shift combinations with clicking or doubleclicking...right mouse click....click on empty area...drag...

Comment: Link is not working.

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice free Windows 8.1 app for designing stripboard/perfboard/breadboard called [DrawingBoard Pro](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-gb/app/drawingboard-pro/43d143ca-29e0-4c53-8009-a3d27765c695) available from the Windows Store.

[image: DrawingBoard Pro screenshot]

Comment: This does not seem to have ERC?

Comment: I find its UI to be utterly inscrutable.

Answer (score 2):

I would add two applications:

- [LochMaster 4.0](http://www.abacom-online.de/uk/html/lochmaster.html)
- [BlackBoard](http://pueski.de/?p=41) Circuit Designer

Comment: Updated location for BlackBoard: https://github.com/mpue/blackboard