# Is this the right layout and can i reduce the number of bridges?

Tags: circuit-design, stripboard

I have this LED light flasher circuit and want to put make it on a veroboard

[image]

This is my first veroboard project and below is my plan for the layout. Will this work and do I need to reduce the number of bridges?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Something seems to be missing from your diagram. Where are the traces (and breaks, if applicable) supposed to be on your board?

Comment: ooh sorry. just going down from the  the middle of the ic there is a break

Comment: You might want to have a look at the (rather dated, and nowadays discouraged) question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/stripboard-veroboard-matrix-board-design-software Frizting is something that arduinistas use a lot for this purpose IIRC. Also comparing the graphics on that page with yours, it seems you haven't defined/use an actual strioboard in DrawingBoard Pro, but you seem to be use a "maxtrixboard" where the dots aren't connected by anything from the factory.

Answer (score 1):

That definitely doesn't look right.

Assuming that the traces on your Veroboard run horizontally, and that there's a gap under the 555 IC, the leads of the capacitor, the two LEDs, and the input diode are each shorted together. This won't work.

Comment: Okay. Do you know how I could change it then? I used the Windows Store Application "DrawingBoard Pro". I would really be grateful if you could show me what to do.